# how to make multiple port search on shodan

Tags: shodan

First of all I'm sorry if this question should be on another forum but I had some difficulties to find out where to ask this and from the site I'm not getting any reply.

Can you tell me how can I search for devices which have 2 or more specific ports open simultaneously because I'm only able to search one at a time?

Comment: You have unreasonable expectations of support. You posted this on StackOverflow an hour after you sent us the support email on new years day. And you can't currently search for devices based on a combination of open ports.

Answer (score -1):

You can use use [search.censys.io](https://search.censys.io) to do something like this:

```
services.port: 17 and services.port: 21
```

[And Results](https://search.censys.io/search?resource=hosts&sort=RELEVANCE&per_page=25&virtual_hosts=EXCLUDE&q=services.port%3A+17+and+services.port%3A+21)

Alternatively if you are looking for either port 17 or port 21 you can use a set like this:

```
services.port: {17, 21}
```

[Or Results](https://search.censys.io/search?resource=hosts&sort=RELEVANCE&per_page=25&virtual_hosts=EXCLUDE&q=services.port%3A+%7B17%2C+21%7D)